# My script in pyqgis run (grass7:I.pca) runs fine but output folder empties

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, landsat, pca

this is my PyQGIS scrpit (QGIS 3.10).  this code runs fine but the output folder doesn't show results.  the MyFeedBack function shows me that it runs correctly and matches the Registry that is generated when the action is performed from the Grass7 i.pca module.  please i need help i don't know what else to try

```
import os
import sys
import gdal

path=r'D:\ESCUELA\clip_L8'
output= r'D:/ESCUELA/PCA'

bandList = [band for band in os.listdir(path)if band[-4:]=='.tif']
input = [os.path.join(path,band) for band in bandList]
print(input)


class MyFeedBack(QgsProcessingFeedback):
   def setProgressText(self,text):
       print(text)
   def pushInfo(self,info):
       print(info)
   def pushCommandInfo(self,info):
       print(info)
   def pushDebugInfo(self,info):
      print(info)
   def pushConsoleInfo(self,info):
      print(info)
   def reportError(self,error, fatalError=False):
      print(error)

def pca(input,output):
params ={'input':input,\
    'rescale':[0.300],\
    'percent':99,\
    '-n':True,\
    '-f':False,\
    'output':output,\
    'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,\
    'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':0}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
res = processing.run("grass7:i.pca",params,feedback=MyFeedBack())
print(res)
return

pca(input,output)
```

Comment: this time use myfeedback to see how the algorithm was running.it doesn't show any error, the code runs fine, but it doesn't give any result. I'm really confused because I dealt with the answer to the previous question that works for @xunilk but not for me.

Comment: Your code doesn't run fine because it doesn't produce any result. You former script, without a class, works perfectly for me. So, the issue is in another place. It could be your paths or your layers.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for your attention, I am going to try it with the original Landsat 8 bands and I will tell you if it works for me